# Call to retrieve a list of messages for a conversation forbidden, the same call works fine in Graph Explorer

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a bot channel registration with configured OAuth Connection Settings. The OAuth Connection Settings specify the following scopes: `Chat.ReadWrite User.Read User.ReadBasic.All email openid profile`.

The corresponding app registration is configured to be accessed by **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)**:
[image: supported account types]

The said app registration has configured permissions as requested by the bot channel registration:
[image: configured permissions]

I can obtain an access token from the bot code using this bot channel registration, by executing the following (after logging in and consenting to the requested permissions):

```cs
await botAdapter.GetAadTokensAsync(
    turnContext,
    oauthConnectionName, // the connection name as configured in the bot channel registration
    new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com" },
    turnContext.Activity.From.Id, // the Teams Id of the action invoker, a.k.a me
    cancellationToken);
```

I use the **Microsoft.Graph.Beta** version 0.12.0-preview nuget package with **Microsoft.Bot.Builder** version 4.7.2 nuget package.

The graph client is constructed like this:

```cs
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((request) =>
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }));
```

Finally, the call which causes the "Forbidden" error message is:

```cs
await graphClient.Chats[conversationId].Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

This corresponds to the Graph API call `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/<conversationId>/messages`. This call, however, succeeds when called from the Graph Explorer.

I can confirm the `scp` claim of the access token contain the permission scopes I mentioned above: `Chat.ReadWrite User.Read User.ReadBasic.All email openid profile`. The same scopes are also in the access token used by the Graph Explorer.

The MS Teams conversation represented by `<conversationId>` is joined by the owner of this access token, as well as the bot.

So why does this call fail from my code, but doesn't fail when called from the Graph Explorer?

Comment: Could you please try putting the access token you get from the code in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and see if it has all the required permissions?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT I have done that. I can confirm the `scp` claim of the access token contain the permission scopes I mentioned above: `Chat.ReadWrite User.Read User.ReadBasic.All email openid profile`

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT I should have probably mentioned that the Teams conversation is a private 1:1 conversation between two people, which is then joined by a bot. Not sure if that changes anything, security wise.

Comment: I'm not seeing a Microsoft.Graph version of "1.21.0-preview" (reference [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/)).  How are you accessing this or where did you acquire the package? I can also successfully test getting chat messages via the Graph Explorer when using the beta API, but I don't see that this has been integrated into the current nuget package ("1.21.0").

Comment: @StevenKanberg it's Microsoft.Graph.Beta 0.12.0-preview ([here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta/))

Comment: Don't know if this is a recent change, but you need ChannelMessage.Read.All permission to read content of a channel.  I was able to consent to this for my org, but elsewhere I read that it was a Protected API requiring Microsoft to enable it. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis)

Comment: And a bit more info.  Graph Explorer isn't an app-only context, so different rules apply.  If you're authenticating with app-only flow and there's a way to look into the raw response body from the request that fails, it might say: "Invoked API requires Protected API access in application-only context when not using Resource Specific Consent..." This means you need Microsoft to enable the app for that API, per the Protected API documentation.